# Converting from a BaseExpandableListAdapter to a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter in a Expandable List View application

Tags: android, expandablelistview

**Expandable list view application**, I trying to change my adapter from a **BaseExpandableListAdapter** (RuleBookAdapter.java) to a **SimpleCursorTreeAdapter** (RuleBookTreeAdapter.java) to access my content provider (TDAProvider).

I used the android SDK ApiDemos ExpandableList2.java as the template to create my (RuleBookTreeAdapter.java).  I'm a novice at Android Development. My goal is to implement the adapter with my content provider so I can produce a more professional application.  I am running into 2 issues when I'm trying to implement this.

**Issue 1)** In the main activity (ActivityRuleBook.java) I've changed it to use the new adapter as follows:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable);
    elv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    elv.setAdapter(new RuleBookTreeAdapter());
//      elv.setAdapter(new RuleBookAdapter(this));
}
```

I get the error "The method setAdapter(ListAdapter) in the type ExpandableListView is not applicable for the arguments (RuleBookTreeAdapter)".  I'm not sure which parameter it is looking for.  I've attempted to find the calling program in the android ApiDemos program to no avail and searched the internet and stackoverflow (suggestions and Similar Questions) and can't find a good example of a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter backed by a cursor, other than ExpandableList2.java from the SDK samples.

**Issue 2)** In the SimpleCursorTreeAdapter (RuleBookTreeAdapter.getChildrenCursor) I'm not sure how to exactly fashion the query to get the child data.

Here is the layout of my 2 tables in my database, with the relevant columns.

**Table: chapters**   (This is the parent table in the application)
Columns: _id, chapter char(2), chaptertitle char(70)
URI: CONTENT_URI chapters

**Table: rules**   (This is the child table in the application)
Columns: _id, rule varchar(10), chapter char(2), ruletitle char(50)
URI: CONTENT_URI_RULES rules

***Note:*** the chapter field in the rules table is the foreign key to the chapters table.  The data in these tables are static, so no update will be occurring and each parent has at least one or more children.

Any help or comments would be appreciated, **thanks in advance** for your time.  Have a great day.

Main Activity source code **ActivityRuleBook.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class ActivityRuleBook extends Activity {

ExpandableListView elv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable);
    elv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    elv.setAdapter(new RuleBookTreeAdapter());
//      elv.setAdapter(new RuleBookAdapter(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.expandable, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**RuleBookAdapter.java** source code. My original BaseExpandableListAdapter using Strings, that worked, that I'm trying to replace.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RuleBookAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
String []grouplist={"01 Chapter","02 Chapter"};
String [][]childlist={
    {
        "01A Follow all rules","01B The USCF RULES"
    },
    {
        "02A The Rules are WRONG","02B The President is right"
    }
};
public RuleBookAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv=new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(childlist[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    tv.setPadding(60, 10, 10, 10);
    return tv;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childlist[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return grouplist.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv=new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(grouplist[groupPosition]);
    tv.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    return tv;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

**RuleBookTreeAdapter.java** source code. The SimpleCursorTreeAdapter (modified from SDK ApiDemos ExpandableList2) **that I am now trying to implement.**  In **getChildrenCursor** I'm not sure how to exactly fashion the query to get the child data from my **rules** table.  It's not clear to me from the ExpandableList2.java example.

```
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.AsyncQueryHandler;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;

/**
* Demonstrates expandable lists backed by Cursors
*/
public class RuleBookTreeAdapter extends ExpandableListActivity {

private static final String[] CHAPTERS_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    TDAdb.KEY_ROWID,
    TDAdb.COL_CHAPTERTITLE
};
private static final int GROUP_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;

private static final String[] RULES_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        TDAdb.KEY_ROWID,
        TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE
};

private static final int TOKEN_GROUP = 0;
private static final int TOKEN_CHILD = 1;

private static final class QueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {
    private CursorTreeAdapter mAdapter;

    public QueryHandler(Context context, CursorTreeAdapter adapter) {
        super(context.getContentResolver());
        this.mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
        switch (token) {
        case TOKEN_GROUP:
            mAdapter.setGroupCursor(cursor);
            break;

        case TOKEN_CHILD:
            int groupPosition = (Integer) cookie;
            mAdapter.setChildrenCursor(groupPosition, cursor);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    // Note that the constructor does not take a Cursor. This is done to avoid querying     the 
    // database on the main thread.
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, int groupLayout,
            int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom,
            int[] childrenTo) {

        super(context, null, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout,   childrenFrom,
                childrenTo);
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        // Given the group, we return a cursor for all the children within that group 

        // Return a cursor that points to this chapters rules
        Uri.Builder builder = TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI_RULES.buildUpon();
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, groupCursor.getLong(GROUP_ID_COLUMN_INDEX));
//            builder.appendEncodedPath(TDAProvider.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Uri rulesUri = builder.build();

        mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_CHILD, groupCursor.getPosition(), rulesUri, 
                RULES_PROJECTION, TDAdb.COL_CHAPTER + "=?", 
                null, null);
//            new String[] { TDAProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }, null);

        return null;
    }
}

private QueryHandler mQueryHandler;
private CursorTreeAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { TDAdb.COL_CHAPTERTITLE }, // Name for group layouts
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
            new String[] { TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE }, // Number for child layouts
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(this, mAdapter);

    // Query for chapters
    mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_GROUP, null, TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI,      CHAPTERS_PROJECTION, 
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Null out the group cursor. This will cause the group cursor and all of the child    cursors
    // to be closed.
    mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    mAdapter = null;
}
}
```

For clarity and completeness I'm including my database, database helper, content provider and layout xml files.  I have used this source in other variants of my project and seems to work fine.

**TDAdb.java** source code.

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;


public class TDAdb {

     public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
     public static final String COL_CHAPTER = "chapter";
     public static final String COL_CHAPTERTITLE = "chaptertitle";
    // public static final String KEY_CONTINENT = "continent";

      // Rule Table Columns
      public static final String COL_RULE = "rule";
//    public static final String COL_CHAPTER = "chapter";
      public static final String COL_KEYDESCRIPTOR = "keydescriptor";
      public static final String COL_RULETITLE = "ruletitle";
      public static final String COL_DESCR = "descr";
      public static final String COL_DESCRIPTION = "description";    //LongText
      public static final String COL_LABEL = "label";
      public static final String COL_USERLABEL = "userlabel";
      public static final String COL_LABELID = "labelid";           //Integer
      public static final String COL_USERLABELID = "userlabelid";   //Integer
      public static final String COL_TDTIP = "tdtip";
      public static final String COL_DEFUNCT = "defunct";
      public static final String COL_USCFREVISION = "uscfrevision";
      public static final String COL_HIGHLIGHT = "highlight";       //LongText
      public static final String COL_PAGENO = "pageno";
      public static final String COL_CHANGEDATE = "changedate";     //Integer
      public static final String COL_REFINC = "refinc";
      public static final String COL_RULEINC = "ruleinc";

     private static final String LOG_TAG = "CountriesDb";
     public static final String CHAPTER_TABLE = "chapters";
     public static final String RULE_TABLE = "rules";
     public static String SQLITE_TABLE = "chapters";

/*   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
      "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + CHAPTER_TABLE + " (" +
       KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
       COL_CHAPTER + "," +
       COL_CHAPTERTITLE + "," +
    //   KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
       " UNIQUE (" + COL_CHAPTER +"));"; */

     public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
//    Log.w(LOG_TAG, DATABASE_CREATE); 
//    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
          Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
     }

     public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
//    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CHAPTER_TABLE);
      onCreate(db);
     }
}
```

**TDAdbHelper.java** source code (included for completeness)

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class TDAdbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     private static String DATABASE_PATH;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tda.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private Context context;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;

 TDAdbHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  this.context = context;
  String packageName = context.getPackageName();
  DATABASE_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
  Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... before calling openDatabase ");
openDataBase();
  Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... after return openDatabase ");
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... Starting TDAdb.onCreate ");
  TDAdb.onCreate(db);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  TDAdb.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
 }
 //Performing a database existence check
 private boolean checkDataBase() {
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... Starting checkDatabase ");
     SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
     try {
         String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
         checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                       SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
     }
     //Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should 
     // be closed
     if (checkDb != null) {
         checkDb.close();
     }
     return checkDb != null;
 }

 //Method for copying the database
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
     //Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
     //The stream source is located in the assets
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... in copyDataBase ");
     InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

      //Path to the created empty database on your Android device
     String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

      //Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
     OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

      //Copying the database
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
         localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
     //Don’t forget to close the streams
     localDbStream.close();
     externalDbStream.close();
 }
 //This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
 public void createDataBase() {
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... in createDataBase ");
     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
     if (!dbExist) {
         this.getReadableDatabase();
         try {
             copyDataBase();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
             throw new Error("Error copying database!");
         }
     } else {
         Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
     }
 }

 public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
     String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Starting openDatabase " + path);
     if (db == null) {
        createDataBase();
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
             SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
     }

     return db;  
}

}
```

**TDAProvider.java** source code (included for completeness)

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

public class TDAProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private TDAdbHelper dbHelper;
    private static final String TAG = "TDAProvider";

    private static final int ALL_CHAPTERS = 1;
    private static final int SINGLE_CHAPTER = 2;
    private static final int ALL_RULES = 3;
    private static final int SINGLE_RULE = 4;

    // authority is the symbolic name of your provider
    // To avoid conflicts with other providers, you should use
    // Internet domain ownership (in reverse) as the basis of your provider
    // authority.
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.birdsall.peter.contentprovider";

    // create content URIs from the authority by appending path to database
    // table
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/chapters");

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_RULES = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/rules");

    // a content URI pattern matches content URIs using wildcard characters:
    // *: Matches a string of any valid characters of any length.
    // #: Matches a string of numeric characters of any length.
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "chapters", ALL_CHAPTERS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "chapters/#", SINGLE_CHAPTER);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "rules", ALL_RULES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "rules/#", SINGLE_RULE);
    }

    // system calls onCreate() when it starts up the provider.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // get access to the database helper
          Log.i(TAG, "onCreate ");
        dbHelper = new TDAdbHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    // Return the MIME type corresponding to a content URI
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
          Log.i(TAG, "getType ");
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_CHAPTERS:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.birdsall.peter.contentprovider.chapters";
        case SINGLE_CHAPTER:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.birdsall.peter.contentprovider.chapters";
        case ALL_RULES:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.birdsall.peter.contentprovider.rules";
        case SINGLE_RULE:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.birdsall.peter.contentprovider.rules";
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
    }

    // The insert() method adds a new row to the appropriate table, using the
    // values
    // in the ContentValues argument. If a column name is not in the
    // ContentValues argument,
    // you may want to provide a default value for it either in your provider
    // code or in
    // your database schema.
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

          Log.i(TAG, "insert ");
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_CHAPTERS:
            // do nothing
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
        long id = db.insert(TDAdb.CHAPTER_TABLE, null, values);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
    }

    // The query() method must return a Cursor object, or if it fails,
    // throw an Exception. If you are using an SQLite database as your data
    // storage,
    // you can simply return the Cursor returned by one of the query() methods
    // of the
    // SQLiteDatabase class. If the query does not match any rows, you should
    // return a
    // Cursor instance whose getCount() method returns 0. You should return null
    // only
    // if an internal error occurred during the query process.
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        String id;
          Log.i(TAG, "query ");

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        // queryBuilder.setTables(TDAdb.CHAPTER_TABLE);

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_CHAPTERS:
            // do nothing
            queryBuilder.setTables(TDAdb.CHAPTER_TABLE);
            break;
        case SINGLE_CHAPTER:
            queryBuilder.setTables(TDAdb.CHAPTER_TABLE);
            id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(TDAdb.KEY_ROWID + "=" + id);
            break;
        case ALL_RULES:
            // do nothing
            queryBuilder.setTables(TDAdb.RULE_TABLE);
            break;
        case SINGLE_RULE:
            queryBuilder.setTables(TDAdb.RULE_TABLE);
            id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(TDAdb.KEY_ROWID + "=" + id);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
          Log.i(TAG, "query return cursor ");
        return cursor;

    }

    // The delete() method deletes rows based on the seletion or if an id is
    // provided then it deleted a single row. The methods returns the numbers
    // of records delete from the database. If you choose not to delete the data
    // physically then just update a flag here.
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

          Log.i(TAG, "delete ");
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_CHAPTERS:
            // do nothing
            break;
        case SINGLE_CHAPTER:
            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = TDAdb.KEY_ROWID
                    + "="
                    + id
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
        int deleteCount = db.delete(TDAdb.CHAPTER_TABLE, selection,
                selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return deleteCount;
    }

    // The update method() is same as delete() which updates multiple rows
    // based on the selection or a single row if the row id is provided. The
    // update method returns the number of updated rows.
    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
          Log.i(TAG, "update ");
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_CHAPTERS:
            // do nothing
            break;
        case SINGLE_CHAPTER:
            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            selection = TDAdb.KEY_ROWID
                    + "="
                    + id
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection
                            + ')' : "");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
        int updateCount = db.update(TDAdb.CHAPTER_TABLE, values, selection,
                selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
          Log.i(TAG, "update return updateCount ");
        return updateCount;
    }

}
```

My **activity_expadnable.xml** file (included for completeness)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="2dp">

    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks Ken, when I edit the main activity to use a listadapter

```
    elv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new RuleBookTreeAdapter());
```

I get the following errors from logcat:

```
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.birdsall.peter.expandable1/com.birdsall.peter.expandable1.ActivityRuleBook}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.birdsall.peter.expandable1.RuleBookTreeAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.birdsall.peter.expandable1.RuleBookTreeAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at com.birdsall.peter.expandable1.ActivityRuleBook.onCreate(ActivityRuleBook.java:19)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-07 17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-07
```

17:12:31.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2226):  ... 11 more

and implementing the method in RuleBookTreeAdapter causes most of code to error out, since it's a different type of adapter.

Comment: Issue 1: Is `elv` defined as an `ExpandableListView` or a `ListView`? Looks like setAdapter expects a ListAdapter.

Comment: Ken see above, I tried that already.

Comment: elv is defined as a ExpandableListView

Comment: Will have to look into ListAdapter, upon further research into SDK APIDemos Expandablelist2 is more than just a listadapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ken was right about the list adapter, here's my adjusted code for the Activity, took a lot of research.`package com.birdsall.tda;

```
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityChapters extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private Context context;


    private Cursor mChapterCursor = null;
    private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityChapters";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 65, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        mChapterCursor = cr.query(TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                TDAdb.PROJECTION_CHAPTER, null, null, TDAdb.COL_CHAPTER);

        setTitle("USCF Rule Book");
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... setTitle ");

        startManagingCursor(mChapterCursor);

        mExpandableListAdapter = new ChapterExpandableListAdapter(this,
                mChapterCursor, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                new String[] { TDAdb.COL_CHAPTERTITLE },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[] { TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... after mExpandableListAdapter");
        setListAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);

        int groupCount = mExpandableListAdapter.getGroupCount();
        ExpandableListView listView = getExpandableListView();


        ((SimpleCursorTreeAdapter) mExpandableListAdapter)
                .setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

                    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                            int columnIndex) {
                        // parent
                        if (columnIndex == cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_CHAPTERTITLE)) {
                            TextView v = (TextView) view;
                            v.setText((cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_CHAPTER)))
                                    + " - "
                                    + (cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_CHAPTERTITLE)))
                                    + " "       
                                    + (cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_KEYDESC)))
                                    );
//                          v.setPadding(60, 10, 10, 10);
                            v.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));
                            v.setTextSize(16);
//                          v.setMaxHeight(50);
//                          v.setHeight(50);
                            v.setMinimumHeight(50);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            // child
                            if (columnIndex == cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE)) {
                                TextView v = (TextView) view;
                                String currentKeyDescriptor = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_KEYDESCRIPTOR)));
                                String textKeyDescriptor = "";
                                if ((String)currentKeyDescriptor == "1") {
                                    textKeyDescriptor = "Club";
                                } else if ((String)currentKeyDescriptor == "2") {
                                    textKeyDescriptor = "USCF";
                                } else if ((String)currentKeyDescriptor == "3") {
                                    textKeyDescriptor = "TD Tip";
                                } else {
                                    textKeyDescriptor = "???";
                                }

                                Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... KeyDescriptor " + currentKeyDescriptor); 
                                v.setText("   "
                                        + (cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_RULE)))
                                        + " - "
                                        + (cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE)))
                                        + " (" 
                                        + (cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_KEYDESCRIPTOR)))  
                                        + ")" + textKeyDescriptor       
                                        );
                                v.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_blue));


                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... after ExpandableListView");
        setListAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... after setListAdapter");


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExecuteCheckListActivity.class);
        // intent.putExtra("checklist_id", id);
        // startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    public class ChapterExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
        private Cursor dataAdapter;

        public ChapterExpandableListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                int collapsedGroupLayout, int expandedGroupLayout,
                String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout,
                String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {

            super(context, cursor, collapsedGroupLayout, expandedGroupLayout,
                    groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(),
                    "... after super ChapterExpandableListAdapter");
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {

            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(),
                    "... in getChildernCursor before RULES query");
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { (String) (groupCursor
                    .getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(TDAdb.COL_CHAPTER))) };
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            dataAdapter = cr.query(TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI_RULES_DESCRIBED, TDAdb.PROJECTION_RULESDESCRIBED, TDAdb.COL_CHAPTER + " = ? ", selectionArgs, TDAdb.COL_RULE);
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(),
                    "... in getChildernCursor after RULES query");
            startManagingCursor(dataAdapter);
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(),
                    "... in getChildernCursor after Managing Cursor");

            return dataAdapter;
        }

    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        // tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setPadding(60, 10, 10, 10);

        return convertView;
    }

}
`
```